# Network service inactive/Unable to add Wi-Fi network on mac pro

Tags: network, wifi, airport, mac-pro

I have no idea what happened but my Wi-fi network has disappeared completely! The Wi-fi icon found on the top menu bar is gone. I'm unable to create a new Wi-fi network service but only able to connect to the internet via LAN cable. I've checked my system information and it says that my network service is inactive. Not sure if reformatting my laptop would make a difference. HELPPPP![image]

Answer (score 1):

The + sign on the bottom left of the dialog is the button you want to press.

Or switch your location back to automatic if it isn't already.

Comment: Hi dlamblin! Thank you so much fr yr reply! Tried + sign to create new Wi-fi but nothing happens. Not sure if its the airport problem.

Comment: @needhelp Alright, now that's mysterious... It would seem that either the device is broken or the drivers that would support it don't work for you. Sometimes for the latter this is fixed with a permissions fix in the disk utility's repair options.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, however I just want to share my solution for the problem, because the problem almost made me nuts and I hope my solution is simple enough and works so someone doesn't have to pull his/her hairs off.

This is my simple solution that worked (at least for me). :

1. Goto System Preferences and then goto Network.
2. When the Networkscreen appears, find the Location combo and delete all location that
   you find in there. Now you are left out with only one Location, that
   is 'Automatic'.
3. Find the plus sign at the left bottom o Network
   screen, click it to add new interface, when interface list appears,
   choose Wi-fi and click create.
4. There, you should now see a Wi-fi interface added to the left hand side list.
5. Click Apply to save.
6. That's it, Hope this helps.